# JS dynamic dropdown work on FF, but not on Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I created a dynamic dropdown list where user select a state, the next dropdown menu will show the cities in that state. The codes works in Firefox, but not in chrome. Why this happened?

Here is my script:

```
<?php $cityurl = get_the_city()."/js/data.json";?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    var dataurl = "<?php echo $cityurl; ?>";
        $("#stateid").change(function location() {

            var $dropdown = $(this);
            $.getJSON(dataurl, function(data) {

                var key = $dropdown.val();
                var vals = [];

                switch(key) {
                    case 'State 1':
                        vals = data.city1.split(",");
                        break;
                    case 'State 2':
                        vals = data.city2.split(",");
                        break;  
                    case 'State 3':
                        vals = data.city3.split(",");
                        break;
                    case 'State 4':
                        vals = data.city4.split(",");
                        break;  
                    case 'All':
                        vals = ['Choose a State First'];
                }

                var $jsontwo = $("#cityid");
                $jsontwo.empty();
                $jsontwo.append("<option value='all'>All Regions</option>");
                $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                    $jsontwo.append("<option value='" 
                                     + value + "'>" 
                                     + value 
                                     + "</option>");
                });
           });
    });
});  
</script>
```

I have checked on the Console and Firebug, but no error found.
Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, there is not enough info to go on.  The script looks fine.

Comment: well, i don't know why it work eventually. So it considered solved